# Uncaught TypeError: ctx.fillText is not a function (Javascript Canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, typeerror

```
var ctx = space.getContext("2d"); 
var FPS = 40;
var score = 0;
    function scoring(){
      ctx.font = "20px Helvetica";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#001e52";
      if(score<10){
        ctx.fillText(score, center.x+44.5, center.y+57);
      }
      if(score>=10 && score<=99){
        ctx.fillText(score, center.x+38.9, center.y+57);
      }
      if(score>=100 && score<=999){
        ctx.fillText(score, center.x+33, center.y+57);
      }
      if(score>=1000){
        score=0;
      }
    }
    setInterval(scoring, 1000/FPS);
```

The code above was working on another canvas game I made exactly as presented. Now I copied and pasted it in my new game and it doesn't work (I obviously changed the coordinates and all to fit my new game). When inspecting element on Chrome it gives me this weird error: **Uncaught TypeError: ctx.fillText is not a function** Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to delete a previous instance of the fillText function in order for it to draw the score on the canvas. No idea why, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I looked more carefully and it was `filltext(some arguments)`.
Problem was I was writing it with small T, not with camelCase.

Comment: you should have shared an opinion in the comment section instead of posting a new answer.